# Notepad++ Webkit plugin - Multiple Html

Tags: notepad++, html, plugins, webkit

Is it possible to have multiple html on one command?

ex:

FROM:

```
 content1
 content2
 content3
 content4
```

highlight the list then click a "custom key" then the result should be

```
<ul>
 <li>content1</li>
 <li>content2</li>
 <li>content3</li>
 <li>content4</li>
</ul>
```

is there a custom key to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just one command.

- Download the plugin [**Zen Coding for Notepad++ v0.7**](https://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=Zen.Coding-Notepad%2B%2B.v0.7.zip&can=2&q=).
- Then install the plugin in Notepad++.
- Restart Notepad++.
- Open a new file in notepad++ and type: `table>ul>li*4`

After that press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, and see the magic.